# Search and delete data from RoR database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a beginner in RoR. Some work has been handed over to me by the previous RoR developer, who isn't available now. I have several users in the db, how can I get all the information related to each of the users and also for a single user? Further, the App offers the feature of adding a friend, so, many of the user would have added many friends as well. How can I search for their friends and how can I delete a single friend? I understand that these questions may be very basic, but, I am beginner in RoR, switching from Java profile.

Some details:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]

$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.4
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html) on the Ruby on Rails web site are excellent. Start by reading [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) and [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). They're succinct and easy to read and will get you up to speed in no time.

Comment: You need to read about activerecords in rails. It is ORM used by rails. Documentation is good. I did not face much problem when I had started working in ruby. Google it. Good luck.

Comment: @Jordan: Thank you for the much need help Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice for you would be to read the [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) and [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) Ruby on Rails guides.

Here's a summary of what you'll need to do. Note this assumes your users are stored in a `User` model.

- Find a user by id: `User.find(id)`
- Find a user by email: `User.find_by(email: email)`
- Build relation for all users: `User.all`
- Build relation for users with a certain email: `User.where(email: email)`

Note that the relations don't actually load any data until you being to operate on the data (e.g. `User.where(email: email).each { |u| u.email }`).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, seeing direct examples to questions helps my understanding, so I'll answer couple of your questions with some examples.

Let's say your Model class is "User" and the table is called "users". Then to get an array of all users, you can do this:

```
allUsers = User.all
allUsers.each do |user|
    puts user.name
    # do whatever else you want with the user instance
end
```

To get a single user, you can do this:

```
user = User.where("id" => 1)[0]
```

Note: the reason for the [0] is because User.where(...) returns an array.

If you have multiple conditions for a particular user, you can do:

```
user = User.where("id" => 1, "email" => "blah@blah.com")[0]
```

Hopefully that's a good start. But most queries you'll need can be found here: 
[Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can first exercise this with the rails console.
If you can get the results of all the users information by typing
1.User.all
If you retrieving a specific user; you give a command like:
2.User.first or User.find(n) where n => 1,2,3,..,n.
If you destroying a specific user;you can give command like:
3.User.first.destroy or User.find(n).destroy where n=>1,2,3,...,n
If you can search for the user's friend, you give a command as
4.User.find_by(name:'XYZABC') where 'XYZABC'=> name of the user's friend.
```